# sparse mutilabel last activation/ loss function

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, multilabel-classification

I am developing a multilabel classification model using keras.

If I use `sigmoid` as the last activation function with `binary cross-entropy loss`, I get 98% of accuracy in my first epoch, but its actually not learning anything. It is because I have 800 categories and have an average of 2-3 True positives.

So I changed to using `sigmoid` with `categorical cross-entropy loss` and it seems to work better but I think it is not recommended?

I would like some guidance on what activation and loss I should use in this case. Thanks!